# Trying to find source of motion of a bone in blender 2.8

Tags: bones

I've got an animation which was originally created in 2.78 and Im looking at it in 2.8. 
What I notice is that some bones are animated, but I cannot find the keyframes associated with their motion. Also checking the dopesheet turns up empty. I dont find any parented objects which might be the cause either.

Ive uploaded an example http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51705

Im very interested to know how/where the animation data can be found.

many thanks in advance
Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created some actions then pushed them down from the *Dopesheet* into the *NLA*, so they are playing in the *NLA* and you don't see them in the *Dopesheet* for the moment, it's the *NLA* that is playing. If you want to see one of these actions again in the *Dopesheet* you need to go in the *NLA*, select a strip and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, it will appear in the *Dopesheet*, or you can also reload it directly in the *Dopesheet* / *Action Editor* mode: Select its name in the dropdown menu of the horizontal menu bar.

[image]

Comment: than you! I finally can adjust the animation